# What bluetooth chip / type should be used for a remote control car?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, bluetooth, remote-control, bluetooth-low-energy

I am building a small remote control car to be controlled by bluetooth (iOS and Android). I am having a custom circuit board built, and I want to know what bluetooth chip I should get. I would like the range of the car to be at least 20-30 feet.

Comment: I downvoted because this is a shopping-related question. There are many Bluetooth modules out there, have you looked at any? Did you know that making iOS apps costs alot of money for a little hobby project (if that is what this is)? How much battery supply have you got on the small car - can it do normal high power bluetooth or is BLE (bluetooth 4.0) more suitable?

Comment: I make iOS apps myself. and I was looking for an affordable BLE to test with. Most require large orders and are expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at the [Bluegiga BLE113 module](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble113-bluetooth--smart-module/).  Uses very little power.  Module includes antenna.  Good for 100m.  You don't need to have a separate microcontroller, your application can run on the BLE113 itself (has a user-programmable 8051); however you can also control it via traditional AT commands via a UART connected to a microcontroller.  Even comes with [source code for an iPhone application](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble113-bluetooth--smart-module/evaluation/).

[image]